# How do I make ipympl the Matplotlib backend when using HoloViews?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, holoviews

When using HoloViews the Matplotlib backend (in JupyterLab) seems to get set by default to Agg and I can't figure out how to set it to an interactive backend. Is there a way to do that?

The following seems to work for Matplotlib on its own, but has no effect on figures rendered with `hv.output(... backend='matplotlib')`:

```py
import holoviews as hv
import matplotlib as mpl
hv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib'
%matplotlib ipympl
```

What is the correct way to use ipympl as the Matplotlib backend for HoloViews.

Comment: Does changing on `matplotlib` work? From the [FAQ](https://holoviews.org/FAQ.html)
`HoloViews will not switch Matplotlib backends for you, but when using Matplotlib we strongly recommend selecting the ‘agg’ backend for consistency:
from matplotlib import pyplot
pyplot.switch_backend('agg')`

Comment: @Filipe Matplotlib itself works as expected after `%matplotlib ipympl`. It's just that that has no effect on HoloViews (as near as I can tell).

Comment: I see what you mean now. `Bokeh` seems to work interactively fine, but `%matplotlib ipympl` (or `%matplotlib widget`) doesn't. Probably an incompatibility between `ipympl` and the way `HoloViews` call mpl. Maybe you could add a simple example on the question, to make easier for people to try.